# SSIS Create Deployment Utility setting is not persistent

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, bids

In BIDS 2008 (Visual Studio 2008 with SSIS), the project setting "**CreateDeploymentUtility**" does not seem to persist when the project is re-opened.

Right click on project, choose properties, in the dialog I set this setting to True, save the project, close it re-open it, and the this setting is back to false.

- Is this an issue anyone else has seen?
- Is there a way to hack-up the project file to keep this setting set to **True**?

We are using TFS 2010, I have the vs 2008 service packs (version 9.0.30729.4462 QFE) , Am I missing a hotfix or something?

Comment: I have the same problem almost. I'm using TFS-2010 and BIDS without the support for TFS-manual check-in. We're expected to not check-in the .dtproj.user file to TFS. When I manually remove it the CreateDeploymentUtility setting reverts back to "False". I'll try the below suggested hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not experience this. This setting is stored in *ProjectName*.dtproj.user (surprised me too)

If you're looking to hack, nested under Options for your configuration, add a row

```
<CreateDeploymentUtility>true</CreateDeploymentUtility>
```

My guess would be that the .user file is locked and BIDS isn't letting you update it nor is it checking it out.

Clearing the read-only bit can be done through the command line

```
attrib -r C:\src\ProjectName\ProjectName.dtproj.user
```

Or you can can right-click on the file, select Properties and uncheck `Read-only`

Comment: Yep, BIDS wasn't checking that file out to store the change.   Thanks for the Answer!

Comment: Hmmm, seems like it should work, but doesn't work for me. I placed this element/value as follows:    <Configurations>  
    <Configuration>  
      <Name>Development</Name>  
      <Options>  
        <OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>  
        <CreateDeploymentUtility>true</CreateDeploymentUtility>  but, BIDS-2008 didn't notice it.

Comment: @JMHicks Just checking the obvious, the file did save, correct? Things like TFS lock the files and crappy editors don't always always know they didn't save. Open a new question, let's see how your situation differs from this one.

Comment: @billinkc Yeah, it saved. Here's the Q I opened and I also tossed in a link to this one since it's almost the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989250/create-deployment-utility-setting-breaks-when-dtproj-user-file-is-removed

Answer (score 1):

in my case is not possible to modify the file ProjectName.dtproj.user

- I modified the file adding true
- I saved my file but the the row
  true
  is not added

Comment: <CreateDeploymentUtility>true</CreateDeploymentUtility> this is the row added